# How to integrate SiteMinder SSO Authentication and Windows Authentication for .NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, single-sign-on, siteminder

My problem is this, we have a set of legacy code that runs SiteMinder but very poorly.  It allows Anonymous at IIS and avoids any use of Active Directory.

We are rebuilding this application and would like to integrate SiteMinder with IIS and .NET 4.0.  I know that I can come in and build my own security framework that does everything without the need of a User Name and Password (because we don't want that from SiteMinder), but I was wondering if there is a way to use the built in Windows Authentication (Forms or Windows) to integrate with SiteMinder.

Additionally I saw that older versions of .NET had Passport Authentication, but it has been removed.  I think this might actually solve our problem but it isn't supported in the most recent versions of .NET (I.E. beyond 1.1).

Any and all information regarding SiteMinder integration with ASP.NET 4.0 would be more than welcome.  I've tried to stitch together enough information to get it working.

I know that SiteMinder returns a set of customizable headers.  I want to use the fact that we have a verified Header that contains a Unique Identifier to log a user in, while at the same time using Windows Authentication.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I'd really like it if we could create a guide to integrating SiteMinder and ASP.NET (because I haven't found one) but if anyone knows of something like that please post it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone in the future who comes down here and needs some help here are a couple useful links.

A good blog on Security through SitMinder [here](http://www.coreblox.com/2011/09/setting-the-windows-security-context-with-siteminder/).

This forum is specifically setup for SSO. http://www.ssohelp.com

That should get you started if you are looking for information on SSO and also give you a place where you will find some more specific answers.

Comment: For anyone in the future who comes down here, the above links are now 404's.